# Sort list by best match from another list

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to sort a list by another list, however they are not 100% identical.

```
list1 = ["1 apple","2banana","mango"]
list2 = ["3bana2na 2+", "0.5 mango 1-", "apple2"]

Out: list1_ordered_by_list2 = ["2banana", "mango", "1 apple"]
```

I am happy with using jellyfish.levenshtein_distance() to do the comparison, however I am not sure how to compare each element from list1 with each element from list2 and returning the list1 sorted by list2 order.

It is worth mentioning that my 2 lists are of the same length. However, a more generic solution would be of great value!

Bonus point if I could get mapping between the 2 lists if they had different number of itmes. e.g.

```
list1 = ["1 apple","2banana","mango"]
list2 = ["3bana2na 2+", "0.5 mango 1-", "apple2", "apple"]

Out: list1_ordered_by_list2 = ["1 apple", "2banana", "mango"]
```

This could be quite complex. Please let me know if further clarification is needed.
I hope you can help.
Thanks,

Comment: So you would have 3 * 3 levenshtein distances, how would you go about sorting them? Could you provide some example of how the output would look like please? I'm thinking of creating something like a levenshetein matrix, but not sure what you are expecting in regards to the ordering.

Comment: Output added. I hope this makes sense. It got my head spinning about a bit :)

Comment: The minimum distance for `2banana  = 5`, `apple2 = 3` and `mango = 6`, shouldn't the order be `apple2,2banana,mango`?

Comment: All the work here is creating the mapping. After that it's pretty easy with things like zip. Should it be 1:1 or are you just partitioning into categories? But I'm not seeing any code here.

Comment: Apologies @CeliusStingher, I have just put illustrative list, the order might not be right, but the idea is to sort list1 by position of nearest hit in list2.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I would prefer a non 1:1 match, to keep this as generic as possible (also could be more useful for the community in the future). Let me please edit the lists to make it a 1 to many.

Comment: Why is "1 apple" first when it most closely matches the last two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Lior's `rank` function, you can use the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) to achieve you example output:

```
list1 = ["1 apple","2banana","mango"]
list2 = ["3bana2na 2+", "0.5 mango 1-", "apple2", "apple"]

import difflib

def rank(x):
    dist = [len(list(difflib.ndiff(x, s))) for s in list2]
    return dist.index(min(dist))

>>> sorted(list1, key=rank)
['1 apple', '2banana', 'mango']
```

Or with your first example:

```
list1 = ["1 apple","2banana","mango"]
list2 = ["3bana2na 2+", "0.5 mango 1-", "apple2"]

>>> sorted(list1, key=rank)
['2banana', '1 apple', 'mango']
```

---

It is probably *faster* to use a form of fuzzy matching against a reference list. You can use the [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) or use [get_close_matches](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) from difflib:

```
list1 = ["1 apple","2banana","mango"]
list2 = ["3bana2na 2+", "0.5 mango 1-", "apple2"]

import difflib

def rank2(s, ref=list2):
    try:
        w=difflib.get_close_matches(s, ref)
        return ref.index(w[0])
    except IndexError:
        return len(ref)+1

>>> sorted(list1, key=rank2)
['2banana', '1 apple', 'mango']
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a ranking function based on the `jellyfish.levenshtein_distance()` which returns the index of the minimal distance and hand it to the sort.

```
from jellyfish import levenshtein_distance as ld

list1 = ["1 apple","2banana","mango"]
list2 = ["3bana2na 2+", "0.5 mango 1-", "apple23"]

def rank(x):
    dist = [ld(x, s) for s in list2]
    return dist.index(min(dist))

print(sorted(list1, key=rank))  # --> ['2banana', '1 apple', 'mango']
```

Comment: Thank you Lior.
We were just having a discussion up there to understand if this is easily made into a 1:many relationship. Do you think that is possible, given the ran is already being calculated? I am inclined to add another item to list2 to make the code generic.

Comment: not sure I follow what do you mean by 1 to many here

Comment: Let me do an edit to the question to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

-- Kind of comment below --

Note that the code below shows the actual ld values. We can see that

**(mango) <-> (apple2)** has a "better" ld than **(mango) <-> (0.5 mango 1-)**

The final line of the output shows the index of the element in the sorted list.

```
from jellyfish import levenshtein_distance as ld

list1 = ["1 apple", "2banana", "mango"]
list2 = ["3bana2na 2+", "0.5 mango 1-", "apple2"]
list3 = []
for x in list1:
    offset = 0
    for idx, y in enumerate(list2):
        ld_value = ld(x, y)
        print('({}) <-> ({}) --> {}'.format(x,y,ld_value))
        if idx == 0:
            _min = ld_value
            continue
        else:
            if ld_value < _min:
                _min = ld_value
                offset = idx
    list3.append((x, offset))
    print()
print(list3)
```

output

```
(1 apple) <-> (3bana2na 2+) --> 10
(1 apple) <-> (0.5 mango 1-) --> 10
(1 apple) <-> (apple2) --> 3

(2banana) <-> (3bana2na 2+) --> 5
(2banana) <-> (0.5 mango 1-) --> 10
(2banana) <-> (apple2) --> 7

(mango) <-> (3bana2na 2+) --> 9
(mango) <-> (0.5 mango 1-) --> 7
(mango) <-> (apple2) --> 6

[('1 apple', 2), ('2banana', 0), ('mango', 2)]
```